# iOS simultaneous translation and scaling issue (CAAnimation)

Tags: ios, translation, scaling, simultaneous

I have a method which translates a view and optionally scales it while translating. I am using animation groups and adding the required animations as needed. Here are the animation cases working perfectly.

1. Translation (x or y axis or both) (OK)
2. Scaling (OK)
3. Translation ***while*** scaling (MOSTLY)

However, doing a translation *while* scaling works only when the starting scalefactor is 1. When the view is already scaled, I notice most of the transition jumping instead of animating, although the end result of scaling and translation is correct.

I am posting part of the code for clarification. The problem occurs only when `previousZoomScale` is not 1! I appreciate any directions you can point me to.

---

```
-(void)performAnimationForView: (AnimationType)animationType
                        WithDX: (CGFloat)dx
                         AndDY: (CGFloat)dy
                         Scale: (CGFloat)scale
                      Duration: (CGFloat)duration
{
    CABasicAnimation *translateXAnimation = nil,     *translateYAnimation = nil, *scaleAnimation = nil;
    NSString* animationGroupName;

    CGPoint newDxDy;

    switch (animationType)
    {

        case kAnimationTranslateAndScale:
            // set animation key
            animationGroupName = @"translatescale";

            translateXAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
            translateXAnimation.repeatCount = 0;
            translateXAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
            translateXAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
            translateXAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            translateXAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: self.previousDxDy.x]; // previous point we're tranlsating from
            translateXAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dx]; // destination point

            translateYAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
            translateYAnimation.repeatCount = 0;
            translateYAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
            translateYAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
            translateYAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            translateYAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: self.previousDxDy.y]; 
            translateYAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dy]; 

            newDxDy = CGPointMake(dx, dy);
            self.previousDxDy = newDxDy;

// scaling animation
            scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
            scaleAnimation.autoreverses = NO;
            scaleAnimation.repeatCount = 0;
            scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
            scaleAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: self.previousZoomScale]; // initial zoom scale
            scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:scale]; // target scale

            self.previousZoomScale = scale;

        break;
    }

    NSMutableArray* animationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

    if (translateXAnimation != nil)
        [animationArray addObject: translateXAnimation];

    if (translateYAnimation != nil)
        [animationArray addObject: translateYAnimation];

    if (scaleAnimation != nil)
        [animationArray addObject: scaleAnimation];

    CAAnimationGroup *theGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

    theGroup.duration = duration;
    theGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    theGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    theGroup.repeatCount = 0;
    theGroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    theGroup.animations = animationArray;
    theGroup.delegate = self;

    [theGroup setValue: animationGroupName forKey: @"animationtype"];

    [self.backgroundImageView.layer addAnimation: theGroup forKey: animationGroupName];
}
```

Comment: Without looking any closer at your specific code - as a hint; such issues commonly arise when the order of transformations is incorrect.

Comment: Tried experimenting with the order of adding the animations to the group, but this had no effect on the end result on screen. What's strange is that the code works for some initial scale values, eg. 1->x, which makes me suspect that I need to take initial scale factor into consideration somewhere in the code.